# Can you jump on a free throw?

Tags: rules, basketball

In basketball can you jump on a free  throw? I have got multiple answers for a bunch of different people that I trust that know a lot about basketball.

Please help me out with this guys, I'm not sure what to think.

Answer (score 6):

> Can you jump on a free throw?

Yes, given the free throw shooter does not leave the defined area at any point during the procedure of a free throw<sub>[(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_throw#Procedure)</sub>.

There is nothing restricting this...

...according to the NBA given the free throw shooter is in compliance with [Rule 9, Section I-A](http://www.nba.com/analysis/rules_9.html):

> When a free throw is awarded, an official shall put the ball in play
>   by placing it at the disposal of the free throw shooter. **The shooter
>   shall be above the free throw line and within the upper half of the
>   free throw circle.**

... according to the NCAA given the free throw shooter is in compliance with [Rule 8, Section 1, Article 1](http://g-macsports.com/custompages/Governance/NCAArulebooks/Basketball_Mens_Rule_Book_2013-2015.pdf):

> A free throw is the privilege given a player to score one point by an
>   unhindered try for goal **from within the free-throw semicircle and
>   behind the free-throw line**.

... according to the FIBA given the free throw shooter is in compliance with [Article 43.1.1](https://www.fiba.com/downloads/Rules/2014/Official_Basketball_Rules_2014_Y.pdf):

> A free throw is an opportunity given to a player to score 1 point,
>   uncontested, **from a position behind the free-throw line and inside the
>   semi-circle**